# Aliasing or otherwise merging two identical object prototypes with different names

Tags: javascript, json, oop, object, inheritance

I've got two object prototypes like this:

```
function Tag(name, description) {
    this.name = name;
    this.description = description || null;
}
function Category(name, description) {
    this.name = name;
    this.description = description || null;
}
```

Both of them are exactly the same, which seems awkward. Is it possible to merge them both into an object named 'Entity', and refer to them both by different names (the original 'Tag' and 'Category')?

This may be further complicated by the fact I need to refer to the current prototype name inside the prototype.

```
Tag.prototype.toJSON = function() {
    return {
        __type: 'Tag',
        name: this.name,
        description: this.description
    };
};
```

How can I apply the same 'toJSON' extension to the 'Entity' object, but make sure it returns 'Tag' or 'Category' in the '__type' field, dependent on which object is being used?

Comment: I wouldn't bother. You code is clearer as it is.

Comment: Fair answer! I'll stick with it then. I'm always keen to learn if there's a better way!

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

```js
Dummy = function () {};

Entity = function (name) {
  this.name = name;
};

Entity.prototype.toString = function () {
  return "My name is " + this.name + ".";
};

A = function () {
  Entity.call(this, 'A');
};

Dummy.prototype = Entity.prototype;
Dummy.prototype.constructor = A;
A.prototype = new Dummy();

B = function () {
  Entity.call(this, 'B');
};

Dummy.prototype = Entity.prototype;
Dummy.prototype.constructor = B;
B.prototype = new Dummy();

document.body.innerHTML = ""
+ (new A()) + "<br />"
+ (new B());
```

Here is a small function to make things cleaner (hopefully):

```
function Nothing () {};

function extend (Sup, proto) {
  function Class () {
    if (this.init) {
      this.init.apply(this, arguments);
    }
  }
  Nothing.prototype = Sup.prototype;
  Nothing.prototype.constructor = Sup;
  Class.prototype = new Nothing();
  delete Nothing.prototype;
  for (var k in proto) {
    Class.prototype[k] = proto[k];
  }
  return Class;
}
```

Here is how to use it:

```
Entity = extend(Nothing, {
  init: function (name) {
    this.name = name;
  },
  toString: function () {
    return "My name is " + this.name + ".";
  }
});

A = extend(Entity, {
  init: function () {
    var sup = Entity.prototype;
    sup.init.call(this, 'A');
  }
});

B = extend(Entity, {
  init: function () {
    var sup = Entity.prototype;
    sup.init.call(this, 'B');
  }
});
```